# javascript getelement where value contains specific string

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I was wanting to count the occurrences of input fields that has a class name of text where that text input contains a specific value.

```
document.getElementById('c_files').getElementsByClassName('text').length;
```

So far this counts all textboxes with the class name of **text** but how can i make it value specific, say if i have 50 textboxes but i only want to count the ones where the value of that textbox *contains* **abc** somewhere within the string.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Thank you everyone for your time and answers, i have voted you all up, but i prefer John Bupit's solution out of them all so thats the one i will accept. Thanks again.

Comment: You just need to do a test. `indexOf()` is probably the function you'll be using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements and see which ones have the desired value:

```
var elems = document.getElementById('c_files').getElementsByClassName('text');

var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if(elems[i].value.match(/abc/)) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select all textboxes first and after that filter those matching your criteria. For example, by using `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
var allText  = document.getElementById('c_files').getElementsByClassName('text'),

    filtered = [].filter.call(allText, function(textbox) {
        return textbox.value.indexOf('abc') > -1;
    });
```

Above code will produce and array of text elements where value contains substring "abc".

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you need to review this SO post-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558906/3748701
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10095064/3748701

This is something which would help in getting your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop over all of the text boxes with the specified class and calculate it from there.

Something like the following logic should work:

```
var counter = 0;
var inputElements = document.getElementById('c_files').getElementsByClassName('text').length;
for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    if (inputElements.value == "someText") {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arriving somewhat late to the party but with a more "up-to-date" solution would be to use `document.evaluate` to leverage the power of XPath expressions.

```js
// utility function 
const getnodes=(expr, parent)=>{
  let results=[];
  let contextNode = parent || document;
  let query = document.evaluate(expr, contextNode, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (let i = 0, length = query.snapshotLength; i < length; ++i) {
    results.push(query.snapshotItem(i));
  }
  return results;
};


// suitable XPath to navigate DOM and find elements of interest
let expr='//*[ @id="c_files" ]/input[ @class="text" ][ contains(@value,"abc") ]';
let col=getnodes(expr);

if( col.length > 0 )console.log(col);
```

```html
<form id='c_files'>
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='abcdef'><!-- this -->
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='defghi'>
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='hijklm'>
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='nopqrs'>
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='tuvwxy'>
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='wxabcyz'><!-- this -->
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='abcxyz'><!-- this -->
  <input class='text' name='f[]' value='defacb'>
</form>
```