# Get td element by value

Tags: javascript

i am trying to change certain td value color, but since it doesnt have any id how should i get it with javascript?

```
<td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mark</td>
<td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
<td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alex</td>
```

For example i wish to change "Mary"  to red color, how can i achive it without knowing any div or id ?

```
var mary = ....?
mary.style.color = "#ff0000";
```

Comment: You can use jQuery [link](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

Comment: @KamilSocha Please don't suggest jQuery when it's neither tagged, nor asked for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751062/js-dom-get-elements-by-text-content , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813294/how-to-get-element-by-innertext , and there are more, just pick yours ...

Answer (score 3):

Use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the reference of targeted elements then iterate these elements and validate their text using `textContent` property.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td.fieldlabel').forEach(function(x) {
  if (x.textContent.trim() == 'Mary') {
    x.style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mark</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *know the position* where "mary" is, you can change the color directly.

```js
var secondTd = document.getElementsByClassName("fieldlabel")[1];
secondTd.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mark</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If OP knows the position then `.fieldlabel:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}` would work no need of JS

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple `<table></table>` wrapper. You can change the color by value with `changeColorByValue()` or by coordinates with `changeColorByCoords()`(*this method is using zero based coordinates this means if you want to refer to first row you pass 0*).

`changeColorByValue()` accepts as first parameter the value that should be searched for, second parameter is the new color and third(*optional*) is if the search should continue after match. Check the dome code.

Have a look on the code and tell me if something is unclear

```js
var table = new Table('myTable');
table.changeColorByValue('Mary', '#ff0000');
table.changeColorByValue('Chris', 'orange', true);
table.changeColorByCoords(1, 2, 'green');

function Table(tableId) {
  var self = this;
  self.table = document.getElementById(tableId);

  self.changeColorByValue = function(sought, color, stopOnFirstMatch) {

    var table = self.table;
    var stopOnFirst = typeof stopOnFirstMatch !== 'undefined' ? stopOnFirstMatch : false;
    
    exit:
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        if (col.innerHTML === sought) {
          col.style.color = color;
          if (stopOnFirst) {
            break exit;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  }

  self.changeColorByCoords = function(row, col, color) {
    try {
      self.table.rows[row].cells[col].style.color = color;
    } catch (e) {}
  }

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mark</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Chris</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alan</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Brian</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Chris</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">John</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is just meant to be an addition to Satpal's answer.*

A more functional approach:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.fieldlabel'))
    .filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === 'Mary')
    .forEach(x =>x.style.color = "#ff0000");
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mark</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming there is only one element containing "Mary":

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.fieldlabel'))
    .find(el => el.textContent.trim() === 'Mary')
    .style.color = "#ff0000";
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mark</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Mary</td>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Alex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```